# How to check whether the customer logged in or not using data attribute in template without using block?

Tags: login, magento2.2, product-review

**I have Link to open a popup modal. But before open the popup it should check whether the customer is logged in or not? If logged in It will show my popup modal else it should show one alert**
**template file**
**I have mentioned below code in my template**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$context = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context');
$isLoggedIn = $context->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
if ($isLoggedIn):

    $class = "action add add-your-review";

else:
    $class = "open-login-poup";

endif;
```

How do I get customer id or name using data attribute in my template

**js file**

```
 function ($) {
            "use strict";
            // Review form 
            var abc = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                buttons: false,
                title: "Header contant",
                modalClass: "popup-center xxx-product-review",
                clickableOverlay: true,
                heightStyle: "content"
            };
            var xxx = $('#review-form-content-wrapper').modal(abc);
            $(".add-your-review").click(function () {
                xxx.modal("openModal");
            });


            return function (config) {
                $('#review-form').on("click", "#review-submit", function () {
                    var form_data = $("#review-form").serialize();
                    var reviewurl = config.url;
                    $.ajax({
                        url: reviewurl,
                        type: 'POST',
                        // Pass the submitted form data to Controller
                        data: form_data,
                        success: function (response) {

                            var returnedData = JSON.parse(response);
                            if (returnedData.status === 'success')
                                $("#success").html(returnedData.messages);
                            else
                                $("#error").html(returnedData.messages);
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            var returnedData = JSON.parse(response);
                            $("#error").html(returnedData.messages);
                        }

                    });
                    return false;

                });
            };

        });
```

Comment: please add you code which you have tried for popup model?

Comment: @Rakesh I have updated the post

Comment: have you used any phtml file?

Comment: I have updated my post @ Abdul

Comment: If you need I will update my full template file

Comment: @Sri add my ans pls check and let me know any queries

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

First add below code in your `.phml` file

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
$class = "";
if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn()):
    $class = "action add add-your-review";
else:
    $class = "open-login-poup";

endif;
?>
<script>
    window.isCustomerLoggedClass = "<?php echo $class ?>";
</script>
```

After get this class name in your `js` file

```
var customerLoggedClass = window.isCustomerLoggedClass;
console.log(customerLoggedClass);
```

Same way your got customer id , name & more...

for eg.

`.phtml` file

```
<script>
        window.customerId = "<?php echo $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId() ?>";
</script>
```

In `js` file

```
var customerId = window.customerId;
    console.log(customerId);
```

After run below command,

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu need to define **if(customer.isLoggedIn()){}**
for check whether customer is guest or login.

```
 define(
    [
        'jquery',        
        'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer'
    ],
 function ($,customer) {
            "use strict";
            // Review form 
            var abc = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                buttons: false,
                title: "Header contant",
                modalClass: "popup-center xxx-product-review",
                clickableOverlay: true,
                heightStyle: "content"
            };
            var xxx = $('#review-form-content-wrapper').modal(abc);
            $(".add-your-review").click(function () {
                if(customer.isLoggedIn())
                    xxx.modal("openModal");
                else
                    alert('guest customer not allowed');
            });


            return function (config) {
                $('#review-form').on("click", "#review-submit", function () {
                    var form_data = $("#review-form").serialize();
                    var reviewurl = config.url;
                    $.ajax({
                        url: reviewurl,
                        type: 'POST',
                        // Pass the submitted form data to Controller
                        data: form_data,
                        success: function (response) {

                            var returnedData = JSON.parse(response);
                            if (returnedData.status === 'success')
                                $("#success").html(returnedData.messages);
                            else
                                $("#error").html(returnedData.messages);
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            var returnedData = JSON.parse(response);
                            $("#error").html(returnedData.messages);
                        }

                    });
                    return false;

                });
            };

        });
```

run command,

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: Thank you, it shows below error       Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isLoggedIn' of undefined

Comment: please check using clear browser cache and try

Comment: I have cleared the browser cache but while clicking link it shows the above error what i mentioned above

Comment: Still error diaplayed

Comment: I think its the way to get customer logged in or not in magento 2 using ko/js, I am not aware other way.

Comment: Okay, Then Why the error occurs? Do you know any other way? Sorry if i am wrong

Comment: no i have worked with above way using js and its works. you can also check from default js file to get customer status in js from /vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/action/place-order.js at line 26

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70855/discussion-between-sri-and-rakesh-jesadiya).